# Building qt 4.8 from source for macOS

Tags: macos, qt4

I'm having problem with building Qt4.8.7 from my macOS (currently 10.14).
I'm following the instruction from [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/install-mac.html), but when I run
./configure
I encounter a warning
   warning: 'LSFindApplicationForInfo' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.10 - Use LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier instead
and then an error
   warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
In file included from project.cpp:42:
In file included from ./project.h:45:
In file included from /Users/opentechiz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7/include/QtCore/qstringlist.h:1:
In file included from /Users/opentechiz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstringlist.h:47:
In file included from /Users/opentechiz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7/include/QtCore/qlist.h:1:
In file included from /Users/opentechiz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:45:
In file included from /Users/opentechiz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7/include/QtCore/qiterator.h:1:
/Users/opentechiz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qiterator.h:50:11: fatal error: 'new' file not found

## include  // No-op, indirectly include additional configuration headers.

Could anyone give me an idea what the error is and how to fix it? or a link to a guide to build Qt4.8 on the macOS?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem here.